# Will Google ban my extension if it sends the whole active tab DOM to my backend?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that will analyze web pages loaded from any tab on chrome.

The analysis will happen on the backend side, so I need to send some HTML content to it (maybe the whole page).

Will my extension be accepted or will it be considered as a security breach and banned?

Comment: They shouldn't care as long as you **PROMINENTLY** declare what your extension does in the description on the web store page.

Comment: I think later on they will ban your extension. As the DOM data may have some confidential data which will passed to your server.